# How to connect multiple bootstrap versions?

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I have a project on laravel which uses bootstrap 4. I want to connect there summernote which uses bootstrap 3. How is it possible to do this?

Comment: create 2 diff blade contain bootstrap 3 and 4.. the include in main blade

Answer (score 0):

There is a variant of Summernote that supports BS4.  See the GitHub repo. and select the `feature/bootstrap4` branch.

Comment: Summernote for bs4 is in beta version. Styles are different from the bs3 version, so it's probably better to change the editor, can you recommend something similar?